# buildozer fail to install android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

**Greeting**

im new to kivy and ive wanted to compile a kivy app for android using buildozer but buildozer fail to install android ndk . the link that buildozer use is outdated and is no longer available im using raspbian latest version

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (armhf).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/pi/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/pi/Downloads/New/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/pi/Downloads/New/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 5a94d074 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2244 from Chronolife-team/native_services_upstream
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/buildozer", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1047, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 169, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 665, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 457, in _install_android_ndk
    cwd=self.buildozer.global_platform_dir)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 677, in download
    urlretrieve(url, filename, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1824, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 620, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

this is the error i have got from termianl

Comment: This looks like a buildozer bug, but I think you'll have the deeper problem that none of the official NDKs will run on the rpi.

Answer (score 1):

To my Knowledge it is not supported on Raspberry PI **HARDWARE** (If you want you can try to use RPI),but I am not sure about raspbian , Anyway the link in buildozer is old so you will have to download the NDK for yourself at the this [location](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip).Then extract the zip to the following location: `/home/NAME/.buildozer/android/platform`.
Then you should be good to go when you run the command.